# PHP round value to it's own size (ten, hunderd, thousand)

Tags: php, rounding, ceil

I want to make a function that round up to its own size of the value.

Example:

```
5    => 10
51   => 60
100  => 100/200 // i don't mind which it will become
121  => 200
999  => 1000
1001 => 2000
```

How can i do this within PHP. I know this can be done using ceil/round but i don't know how.

Comment: How does 5 become 10 if the definition of dozen is "a group or set of twelve"?

Comment: Why 51 becomes 60 and 121, 200 ? What's the logic behind it ? And up to  10000 what that would be ? 100000 ?

Comment: Either you round to the nearest tens, or hundreds or thousands or ten thousands. Your question does not follow a specific pattern.

Comment: Whatever number this is rounding to, it's definitely not a dozen!

Comment: it seems the translation is wrong but what i want is that it rounded to the nearest higher value within it own size (ten, hunderd, thousand etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be You mean this

```
function Myround(array $numbers)
{
    $new_numbers = [];
    foreach ($numbers as $num) {
        $rozriad = strlen($num)-1;
        $new_numbers[] = round(ceil($num/pow(10, $rozriad))*pow(10, $rozriad), -$rozriad);
    };
    return $new_numbers;
};

$dozens = [5, 51, 100, 121, 999, 1001];

print_r(Myround($dozens));
```

Comment: Looks clean and readable but were does $rozriad comes from and what does it contain?

Comment: @IMarks, i changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following function:

```
/**
 * by Johannes Schuh, Pineapple Developer
 */ 
function roundIt($number) {
    $amount = 0;
    do {
        $number = $number / 10;
        $amount++;
    } while($number >= 10);
    $result = 0;
    $result = $number - fmod($number, 1);
    $result++;
    $result = $result * pow(10, $amount);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: By the way: 100 outputs 200

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. Glad you understood what i wanted despite i used the wrong translation.